# Dummy index automatic summing

Tags: pattern-matching, summation

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/222410/73364
I have obtained the following code from the above link. But it is not working well with my situation. Can anyone help me out?

```
SumHeld /: 
  SyntaxInformation[
   SumHeld] = {"LocalVariables" -> {"Table", {2, Infinity}}};

IndexUnify[HoldPattern@Plus[sums : SumHeld[_, __] ..]] := 
 Plus @@ With[{targetIndices = List @@ #[[-1, 2 ;;, 1]], 
      sourceIndicesList = List @@@ #[[;; , 2 ;;, 1]]}, 
     Function[{sum, sourceIndices}, 
       sum /. Thread[
         sourceIndices -> 
          Take[targetIndices, Length@sourceIndices]]] @@@ 
      Transpose@{#, sourceIndicesList}] &@
  SortBy[Flatten /@ {sums}, Length]

SumTogether[HoldPattern@Plus[sums : SumHeld[_, sameRanges__] ..]] := 
 SumHeld[Plus @@ {sums}[[;; , 1]], sameRanges]
SumTogether[HoldPattern@Plus[sums : SumHeld[_, __] ..]] /; 
  UnsameQ @@ {sums}[[;; , 2 ;;]] := 
 Plus @@ SumTogether@*Plus @@@ GatherBy[{sums}, Rest]
```

Here please see the below test case.

```
test = SumHeld[f[a, i], {a, 1, 5}, {i, 1, 5}] + 
  SumHeld[SumHeld[2*f[b, j], {b, 1, 5}], {j, 1, 5}] + 
  SumHeld[SumHeld[2*f[c, j], {c, 1, 5}], {j, 1, 5}]
% // IndexUnify
% // SumTogether
```

The output I am receiving is

$$\text{SumTogether}\left(\sum _{c=1}^5 \sum _{j=1}^5 f(c,j)+2 \sum _{c=1}^5 \sum _{j=1}^5 2 f(c,j)\right)$$

Here the issue is it's not simplifying further as $$\left(\sum _{c=1}^5 \sum _{j=1}^55f(c,j)\right)$$

Another question is when I have more than 2 summation signs as below:

```
test = SumHeld[f[a, i, j], {a, 1, 5}, {i, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 5}] + 
  SumHeld[SumHeld[2*f[b, j, i], {b, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 5}], {i, 1, 5}] + 
  SumHeld[SumHeld[2*f[c, j, i], {c, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 5}], {i, 1, 5}]
% // IndexUnify
% // SumTogether
```

Is the bracket I have placed correctly?

Comment: 1. `SumHeld[SumHeld[2*f[b, j]], {b, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 5}]` should be `SumHeld[SumHeld[2*f[b, j], {b, 1, 5}], {j, 1, 5}]`, right? 2. $$\left(\sum _{c=1}^5 \sum _{j=1}^53f(c,j)\right)$$ should be $$\left(\sum _{c=1}^5 \sum _{j=1}^55f(c,j)\right)$$, isn't it?

Comment: @xzczd You are correct. I have edited.  But that is not affecting the output! Also if I have 4 summations, say i,j,k,l,  how can I write the bracket. It's not working

Comment: @Jasmine In fact, you don't have to be confused with so many brakets. You can use the flat form as `SumHeld[2*f[b, j], {b, 1, 5}, {j, 1, 5}]` instead of the folded form `SumHeld[SumHeld[2 f[b, j], {b, 1, 5}], {j, 1, 5}]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you observe the definition of `SumTogether` carefully, you'll find it only works on `SumHeld[…]` with no coefficient. So we need to define a rule for `SumHeld[…]` with coefficient:

```
SumHeld /: c_?NumericQ SumHeld[rest_, range__] := SumHeld[c rest, range]
```

Comment: My results are now as I am expecting. Great

Comment: I would like to know whether there are any other simple code to handle more than 50 sums. I meant it is difficult to write and give summation to each terms. Can I give summation all at a once?