# Summation without writing term by term

Tags: pattern-matching, summation

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/222410/73364
I have obtained the following code from the above link

```
SumHeld /: MakeBoxes[SumHeld[expr_, ranges__], form_] := 
 MakeBoxes[Sum[expr, ranges], form]

SumHeld /: 
  SyntaxInformation[
   SumHeld] = {"LocalVariables" -> {"Table", {2, Infinity}}};

IndexUnify[HoldPattern@Plus[sums : SumHeld[_, __] ..]] := 
 Plus @@ With[{targetIndices = List @@ #[[-1, 2 ;;, 1]], 
      sourceIndicesList = List @@@ #[[;; , 2 ;;, 1]]}, 
     Function[{sum, sourceIndices}, 
       sum /. Thread[
         sourceIndices -> 
          Take[targetIndices, Length@sourceIndices]]] @@@ 
      Transpose@{#, sourceIndicesList}] &@
  SortBy[Flatten /@ {sums}, Length]

SumTogether[HoldPattern@Plus[sums : SumHeld[_, sameRanges__] ..]] := 
 SumHeld[Plus @@ {sums}[[;; , 1]], sameRanges]
SumTogether[HoldPattern@Plus[sums : SumHeld[_, __] ..]] /; 
  UnsameQ @@ {sums}[[;; , 2 ;;]] := 
 Plus @@ SumTogether@*Plus @@@ GatherBy[{sums}, Rest]
```

It's working perfectly with another suggestion from @xzczd

```
SumHeld /: c_?NumericQ SumHeld[rest_, range__] := SumHeld[c rest, range]
```

If I need to do a summation for example:

$$\text{Test1}=x_{a,c} x_{b,d} K_{a,b,c,d}+x_{a,b} x_{c,d} K_{a,b,c,d}$$

ie,

```
 Test1 = Subscript[K, a, b, c, d]* Subscript[x, a, b]*
   Subscript[x, c, d] + 
  Subscript[K, a, b, c, d]* Subscript[x, b, d]*Subscript[x, a, c]
```

It works perfectly,  but the drawback is I need to write each term. ie, If I need the answer I have to write the code as:

```
 SumHeld[Test1[[1]], {a, 1, 5}, {b, 1, 5}, {c, 1, 5}, {d, 1, 5}] + 
 SumHeld[SumHeld[Test1[[2]]], {a, 1, 5}, {b, 1, 5}, {c, 1, 5}, {d, 1, 
   5}]
% // IndexUnify
% // SumTogether // FullSimplify
```

This is not possible if I have 100 terms!!! So is there any possibility to get the answer without writing term by term summation?

I can show an example:
$$\text{p5}=4 M x_{i,q} x_{k,l} g_{i,k,l,p}-4 M x_{i,p} x_{k,l} g_{i,k,l,q}-2 x_{i,q} x_{k,l} g_{i,k,l,p}+2 x_{i,p} x_{k,l} g_{i,k,l,q}-4 M x_{j,p} x_{k,l} g_{j,k,l,q}+4 M x_{j,q} x_{k,l} g_{j,k,l,p}-2 x_{j,q} x_{k,l} g_{j,k,l,p}+2 x_{j,p} x_{k,l} g_{j,k,l,q}$$

Both x and g  are antisymmetric tensors. So here to perform the summation I have to write as:

```
p5=2 Subscript[g, i, k, l, q] Subscript[x, i, p] Subscript[x, k, l] - 
 4 M Subscript[g, i, k, l, q] Subscript[x, i, p] Subscript[x, k, l] - 
 2 Subscript[g, i, k, l, p] Subscript[x, i, q] Subscript[x, k, l] + 
 4 M Subscript[g, i, k, l, p] Subscript[x, i, q] Subscript[x, k, l] + 
 2 Subscript[g, j, k, l, q] Subscript[x, j, p] Subscript[x, k, l] - 
 4 M Subscript[g, j, k, l, q] Subscript[x, j, p] Subscript[x, k, l] - 
 2 Subscript[g, j, k, l, p] Subscript[x, j, q] Subscript[x, k, l] + 
 4 M Subscript[g, j, k, l, p] Subscript[x, j, q] Subscript[x, k, l]

SumHeld[p5[[1]], {i, 1, 5}, {k, 1, 5}, {l, 1, 5}] + 
  SumHeld[SumHeld[p5[[2]]], {i, 1, 5}, {k, 1, 5}, {l, 1, 5}] + 
  SumHeld[SumHeld[p5[[3]]], {i, 1, 5}, {k, 1, 5}, {l, 1, 5}] + 
  SumHeld[SumHeld[p5[[4]]], {i, 1, 5}, {k, 1, 5}, {l, 1, 5}] + 
  SumHeld[SumHeld[p5[[5]]], {j, 1, 5}, {k, 1, 5}, {l, 1, 5}] + 
  SumHeld[SumHeld[p5[[6]]], {j, 1, 5}, {k, 1, 5}, {l, 1, 5}] + 
  SumHeld[SumHeld[p5[[7]]], {j, 1, 5}, {k, 1, 5}, {l, 1, 5}] + 
  SumHeld[SumHeld[p5[[8]]], {j, 1, 5}, {k, 1, 5}, {l, 1, 5}];
% // IndexUnify;
p5n = % // SumTogether
```

It's really hard to write it as above for only 8 terms. Then think about 50 or 100 terms!

What I got after the code is:
$$8 M x_{i,j} x_{l,q} g_{i,j,l,p}-8 M x_{i,j} x_{l,p} g_{i,j,l,q}-4 x_{i,j} x_{l,q} g_{i,j,l,p}+4 x_{i,j} x_{l,p} g_{i,j,l,q}$$

Is there a way to get the same answer in a different manner without writing each terms into the sumheld?

Comment: If your hundreds of data are in a file, `Import[ ]` it.

Comment: It's not in a file. There are 100 terms in a sum.

Comment: Are you looking for `Map`?

Comment: I am not sure how to modify above code to get summation without adding seperate terms. For Eg: It might be great if I get an answer just by writing, SumHeld[Test1]

Comment: It seems that I am missing something in the question. You have 100 terms. The terms are truly different rather than merely a variable with a changing counter subscript. The question is not about importing outside data. Then it sounds like you need to input each of the hundred different items to be summed, no?

Comment: I have modified the question with another example to elaborate on what I am looking for. Can you please have a look?

Comment: Are the `SumHeld[SumHeld[…` typos?

Comment: No it's not typo. We should right like that to get that answer

Comment: You need to add @xzczd in your comment or I won't get the reminder.  (As to the usuage of @ , you may want to read this post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/284701) Once again, are you sure things like `SumHeld[ p5[[2]] ]` are correct?

Comment: @xzczd Sure I can put like that. I am getting answer using that expression.

Comment: So, the first term should be `SumHeld[…`, and the rest terms should be `SumHeld[SumHeld[…`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123564/discussion-between-jasmine-and-xzczd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SumHeld[expr_, {lst_List, dim_}] := (term |-> SumHeld[term, ##] & @@ 
    Table[If[Count[term, patt, ∞] == 2, {patt, dim}, Nothing], {patt, lst}]) /@ expr    

SumHeld[p5, {{i, j, k, l}, 5}]
```

[image]

If you prefer the convention $$\sum _{i=1}^5$$

Modify the `{patt, dim}` to `{patt, 1, dim}`.

Comment: Incredibly simple!!! Awesome code

Comment: There is another issue popping up! Can you please have a look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/245585/simplifying-the-summation