# Simplifying the Summation

Tags: simplifying-expressions, pattern-matching, tensors

I have to sum:
$$\frac{1}{2} x_{i,k} x_{j,\nu } g_{i,j,k,\mu }+\frac{1}{2} x_{i,k} x_{j,\mu } g_{i,j,k,\nu }+x_{i,l} x_{j,\nu } g_{i,j,l,\mu }+x_{i,\mu } x_{k,l} g_{i,k,l,\nu }$$

g and x  are real antisymmetric tensors.

I have the following code to perform summation.

```
SumHeld /: MakeBoxes[SumHeld[expr_, ranges__], form_] := 
 MakeBoxes[Sum[expr, ranges], form]

SumHeld /: 
  SyntaxInformation[
   SumHeld] = {"LocalVariables" -> {"Table", {2, Infinity}}};
SumHeld /: c_?NumericQ SumHeld[rest_, range__] := 
 SumHeld[c rest, range]
IndexUnify[HoldPattern@Plus[sums : SumHeld[_, __] ..]] := 
 Plus @@ With[{targetIndices = List @@ #[[-1, 2 ;;, 1]], 
      sourceIndicesList = List @@@ #[[;; , 2 ;;, 1]]}, 
     Function[{sum, sourceIndices}, 
       sum /. Thread[
         sourceIndices -> 
          Take[targetIndices, Length@sourceIndices]]] @@@ 
      Transpose@{#, sourceIndicesList}] &@
  SortBy[Flatten /@ {sums}, Length]

SumTogether[HoldPattern@Plus[sums : SumHeld[_, sameRanges__] ..]] := 
 SumHeld[Plus @@ {sums}[[;; , 1]], sameRanges]
SumTogether[HoldPattern@Plus[sums : SumHeld[_, __] ..]] /; 
  UnsameQ @@ {sums}[[;; , 2 ;;]] := 
 Plus @@ SumTogether@*Plus @@@ GatherBy[{sums}, Rest]

SumHeld[expr_, {lst_List, 
   dim_}] := (term |-> 
    SumHeld[term, 
     Sequence @@ 
      Table[If[Count[term, patt, ∞] == 2, {patt, dim}, 
        Nothing], {patt, lst}]]) /@ expr
```

It is simplifying to:
$$\frac{3}{2} x_{i,l} x_{k,\nu } g_{i,k,l,\mu }+x_{i,\mu } x_{k,l} g_{i,k,l,\nu }+\frac{1}{2} x_{i,l} x_{k,\mu } g_{i,k,l,\nu }$$

by using the code:

```
 testl = 
 1/2 Subscript[g, i, j, k, ν] Subscript[x, i, k] Subscript[x, 
    j, μ] + 
  1/2 Subscript[g, i, j, k, μ] Subscript[x, i, k] Subscript[x, 
    j, ν] + 
  Subscript[g, i, j, l, μ] Subscript[x, i, l] Subscript[x, 
    j, ν] + 
  Subscript[g, i, k, l, ν] Subscript[x, i, μ] Subscript[x, k, 
    l]


1/2 Subscript[x, i, k] Subscript[x, j, ν] Subscript[g, i, j, 
  k, μ] + 
 1/2 Subscript[x, i, k] Subscript[x, j, μ] Subscript[g, i, j, 
  k, ν] + 
 Subscript[x, i, l] Subscript[x, j, ν] Subscript[g, i, j, 
  l, μ] + 
 Subscript[x, i, μ] Subscript[x, k, l] Subscript[g, i, k, l, ν]

    SumHeld[testl, {{i, j, k, l}, 5}];
    
    % // IndexUnify;
    
 % // SumTogether
```

But this can be further simplified as:

$$\frac{3}{2}x_{i,l}x_{k,\nu}g_{i,k,l,\mu}+x_{i,\mu}x_{k,l}g_{i,k,l,\nu}+\frac{1}{2}x_{i,l}x_{k,\mu}g_{i,k,l,\nu}   
=\frac{3}{2}x_{i,l}x_{k,\nu}g_{i,k,l,\mu}+x_{k,\mu}x_{i,l}g_{k,i,l,\nu}+\frac{1}{2}x_{i,l}x_{k,\mu}g_{i,k,l,\nu}    
=\frac{3}{2}x_{i,l}x_{k,\nu}g_{i,k,l,\mu}+x_{k,\mu}x_{i,l}g_{k,i,l,\nu}-\frac{1}{2}x_{i,l}x_{k,\mu}g_{k,i,l,\nu}    
=\frac{3}{2}x_{i,l}x_{k,\nu}g_{i,k,l,\mu}+\frac{1}{2}x_{k,\mu}x_{i,l}g_{k,i,l,\nu}  $$

Is there any way to automatically do this?

Comment: Numerically or Symbolically?

Comment: Did you try applying Simplify or FullSimplify?

Comment: @bills it’s not working

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ symbolically

Comment: Does $g$ always involve all of the dummy index? I mean, will something like $x_{i,k}x_{i,l}g_{k,l,\mu,\nu}$ exist in the real cases?

Comment: @xzczd Yes. g always involve all of the dummy index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my solution. First, make $x$ and $g$ antisymmetric with proper function definitions as I've done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/226190/1871):

```
Subscript[g, arg__] /; ! OrderedQ@{arg} := 
 Signature@{arg} Subscript[g, ##] & @@ Sort@{arg}
Subscript[x, arg__] /; ! OrderedQ@{arg} := 
 Signature@{arg} Subscript[x, ##] & @@ Sort@{arg}
```

Then define a function to rename the dummy indices. The underlying idea is similar with [asd1dsa's `IndexUnify`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/222410/1871), but I've sorted the indices so that the renaming will be done in a better way:

```
dummyunify[expr_Plus, 
  possibledummylst_] := (term |-> 
    Module[{indexlstold, indexlstnew, varlst = DeleteCases[List @@ term, _?AtomQ]}, 
     indexlstold = 
      DeleteDuplicates@
       Cases[SortBy[Last]@varlst, Alternatives @@ possibledummylst, ∞];
     indexlstnew = possibledummylst[[;; Length@indexlstold]];
     term /. Thread[indexlstold -> indexlstnew]]) /@ expr
```

Test:

```
dummyunify[testl, {i, j, k, l}]
```

$$\frac{1}{2} x_{i,j} x_{k,\mu } g_{i,j,k,\nu }-\frac{3}{2} x_{i,j} x_{k,\nu } g_{i,j,k,\mu }$$

Comment: Amazingly simple. Fingers crossed!